# Two Handle Bathroom Sink Faucet Does not Mix Hot and Cold

Tags: bathroom, faucet

My two-handle bathroom sink faucet suddenly went weak on both cold and hot sides. I can get cold water or hot water (using H or C handle separately) but no warm water. Turning on Cold and then adding the Hot side (and vice versa) does not increase the flow from the faucet spout.

Comment: What happens if you turn on cold, add hot, then turn off cold? Do you get hot water or no flow at all?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I get hot water with no change in flow strength. Normally if I turn on cold and then add hot, the flow from faucet nozzle increases, but there is no additive effect. And it's weak flow overall now.

Comment: Pressure in rest of house is normal, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a chunk of debris in your aerator, reducing total flow. If flow is restricted, you won't see any difference in flow between one faucet and two faucets turned full-on. So try cleaning your aerator.

If you don't know how to clean your aerator, see [this link](https://www.thespruce.com/clearing-a-blocked-faucet-aerator-2718807).

Even before you clean the aerator, you can probably get hot + cold = warm water by turning on one faucet just a trickle, then turning on the other till you get more of a trickle.